# Por que cuando quiero correr un ciclo FOR en python a través de "Jupyter Notebook" me arroja: TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Tags: python, jupyter, anaconda

Este es el ejemplo aunque no entiendo por que no funciona si cuando lo corro en VS funciona:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: solo se me ocurre que hayas definido una variable llamada `print`, lo que obviamente no es buena idea.

Comment: Si Abulafia está en lo cierto, es recomendable evitar llamar a las variables como algo built-in de Python, pues reemplazas la función original. En este caso si haces `print = []` estarías reemplazando la función print por una lista vacía. Si luego quieres imprimir algo con print, en lugar de recurrir a la función print, recurrirá a la lista.

Comment: Yo en lo personal prefiero un intermedio, es decir reemplazar funciones built-in por otra cosa cuando estoy muy seguro de que no usaré el built-in en otro lado. Por ejemplo en muchos casos las funciones `vars` y `type` no las uso.